# change syntax highlighting activation in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, swagger, swagger-ui, syntax-highlighting, wso2-api-manager

Sometimes response of a service is too large that swagger cannot get and beautify response as json.
if we try with "curl" command, we get response very fast. I think this is because of "Syntax highlighting" configuration of swagger.

In this [url](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/877), we can understand that one way is change this config:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.syntaxHighlight.activated=false
```

Do you have any idea in wso2 apim 4.1.0?
Can we change API Definition for this? or we have to change core configs of wso2?

Answer (score 0):

With advanced UI customization you should be able to get this done. Please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/advanced-ui-customization/

You will have to customize the Swagger UI and add the springdoc.swagger-ui.syntaxHighlight.activated property there.
In[1], it is added springdoc.swagger-ui.validatorUrl for the Swagger UI.

[1] -
https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps/blob/main/portals/devportal/src/main/webapp/source/src/app/components/Apis/Details/ApiConsole/SwaggerUI.jsx#L32